# loop thru array and display data in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, display

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlJVL.png)I am very new to angular and I want to loop throu an array in angular. My array har these elements in it.

```
"ticketsdetectives":[10,11,12,13]
```

Now I want to to display this data. So something like this :

```
for(int i=0; i<ticketdetectives.size(); i++){ 
         printf("%d",ticketdetectives[i]);
}
```

My code in angular is like this

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngFor="let string of ticketNames">
                <mat-label>{{string}} tickets:</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" pattern="([0-9]+\s*[,]\s*)*[0-9]+" formControlName="ticketsdetectives"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

ticketNames is just an array of strings. How do I loop thru my array and display data in input. right now my data is displayed as array and I want it to be displayed as elements.

Comment: ticketdetectives is an array and you can't use it as formControlName. Can you explain a little more on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I just edited my question. I added a picture in the question. What I have here is a form where data shown in it is an array. "10,11,12,13". What I want is for Taxi tickets "10" should show up. for Bus tickets "11" and so on. How do I do that.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that your defined array has a different name "ticketsdetectives" in the typescript file and you are using "ticketNames" in the html template

Comment: I added a picture in the question so you can see. What I have here is a form where data shown in it is an array. "10,11,12,13". What I want is for Taxi tickets "10" should show up. for Bus tickets "11" and so on. How do I do that.

Comment: "ticketNames" is just the names "taxi" "bus" "underground" and "boat". Now what my "ticketsdetectives" have is an array of "10,11,12,13" and I want taxi to have 10 and bus to have 11 and so on. That what I mean. I dont understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a local variable in your .ts:

```
tickets = [{name:'taxi', detective: 10}, {name: 'bus', detective:11 }, { name: 'underground',detective: 12 },{ name: 'boat', detective 13 }];
```

In your html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">
                <mat-label>{{ ticket.name}} tickets:</mat-label>
                <input [ngModel]="ticket.detective" matInput type="text" pattern="([0-9]+\s*[,]\s*)*[0-9]+"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

If you want to use formControlName please see the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: btw, if you're new to angular and trying to reach some goal quickly by making little research, you might want to use template driven aproach for forms.

Comment: Hi, I cannot do like this. Since my "ticketsdetectives" and "ticketNames" can actually have different values different times. The values changes when user want to have other values. Thus having these defined values such as "taxi", "bus" or "10,11,12,13" is not good idea.

Comment: What you trying to achieve? I couldn't understand hence i'm unable to help. Is there 2 different arrays and you're trying to show them like in your uploaded picture ?

Comment: Both arrays is input from user so both array cannot have defined values. For example. TicketNames right now have ”Taxi”, ”Bus”, ”underground” and ”boat”. ticketsdetectives have the values ”10”, ”11”, ”12” and 13 and is the amount of tickets corrisponding each name. Meaning that for taxi it should only display 10, for bus only display 11 and so on. Right now for all ticket names it display all numbers as array. But I want it to display one number each.

Comment: And as I told you. The names and values can change so mabey another time the names is helocopter, ship and car and the numer is 16,17 and 18. So this means there should be 3 of these gray layouts as shown in the picture with the new names instead. And the number 16 corrispond to helocopter, 17 to ship and so on. Hopefully this makes it more clear